# GStreamer Pipline with OpenCV on Coral Dev Board

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, google-coral

I am trying to access the CSI Camera on the Coral Dev Board via OpenCV and GStreamer in C++;

This is my pipline code that seems to work fine when testing with gst:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device = /dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1
```

But when trying to open it with OpenCV it doesnt seem to do the trick:

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string pipline = "v4l2src device = /dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1";

  cv::VideoCapture capture(pipline, cv::CAP_GSTRAMER);
  if (!_capture.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Could not open Camera" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also, is there somehow a more detailed error message available via opencv? When running gst-launch-1.0 it tells me quite specifically what it didnt like about my pipline string. But in opencv it just seems to tell me that it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCv `VideoCapture` has [5 overloaded functions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a57c0e81e83e60f36c83027dc2a188e80) and all of them don't include this type implementation. You can use the followings as `VideoCapture` inputs:

- video file or image file sequence
- a capturing device index
- IP video stream link

As I see in your command, your CSI camera locates on `device = /dev/video0` so you can call it simply with the line:

```
  cv::VideoCapture capture(0, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

Comment: So, I am pretty sure it does include this type of implementation. In videoio.hpp there is `CV_WRAP explicit VideoCapture(const String& filename, int apiPreference = CAP_ANY);` with the docs saying for filename param: "or GStreamer pipeline string in gst-launch tool format in case if GStreamer is used as backend..."

Comment: I tried your suggestion and get the same error that isOpen() returns false. What does work is this: `capture(0, cv::CAP_V4L)`
But with this solution it takes ~6ms for fetching an image. I was hoping by using the gstreamer interface I can reduce that time a bit : )
But maybe that is a good enough solution.

Comment: then I am suspicious about you installed opencv with gstreamer flag ON or not

Comment: Yes, built with: `-DWITH_GSTREAMER:BOOL=TRUE`